# Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError: method POST must have a request body

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using retrofit to make a post api call, I am getting the following error while trying to hit the endpoint.

```
     Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: method POST must have a request body.
            at rx.Observable$30.onError(Observable.java:7334)
            at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:154)
            at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:111)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue(OperatorObserveOn.java:197)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:173)
            at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method POST must have a request body.
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder.method(Request.java:236)
            at retrofit.client.OkClient.createRequest(OkClient.java:59)
            at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
```

trying to access a post api

```
 @POST("/service/v2/auth/ip-address")
    rx.Observable<AuthState> verifyIP();
```

actual api call

```
LoginService service = CKRestClient.get().create(LoginService.class);
            service.verifyIP().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(
                    new Action1<AuthState>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(AuthState authState) {

                        }
                    });
        });
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like Retrofit wants POST requests to have a payload. There's already an issue for it: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/854

As a workaround, you could do something like this:

```
@POST("/service/v2/auth/ip-address")
rx.Observable<AuthState> verifyIP(@Body Object dummy);
```

and then do:

```
LoginService service = CKRestClient.get().create(LoginService.class);

service.verifyIP(null).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(
  new Action1<AuthState>() {
    @Override
    public void call(AuthState authState) {
      // ...
    }
  });
});
```

Or, if `service.verifyIP(null)` throws a NPE, replace it with `service.verifyIP("")` or similar.

Comment: Thanks Bart , that worked. I used service.verifyIP("").I had created a sample work around project before jumping into the actual app. I have the same code without this work around in the sample app and it works.

Comment: Why the before work well, now use work failed? i dont know why?

Comment: I suppose this appreas since okhttp 2.4.0. [PR](https://github.com/square/okhttp/commit/1abba290f5e3e7719ad2dfead2eb45d507ed492c#diff-45c7088c522ba4e5ff45fc2bd93fa25aR236)

Comment: is it fixed in new retrofit version, i.e. 2.1.0?

Answer (score 13):

I solved this issue by replacing @Query to @Field, here is how:

Not working code:

```
@POST("/my/url/path")
Result postToServer(
        @Query("user_name") String userName);
```

Working example:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/my/url/path")
Result postToServer(
        @Field("user_name") String userName);
```

For methods that do not have any fields I had to add empty string like below

```
Result postToServer(@Path("my_path") String myPath,
                               @Body String emptyString);
```

And call it passing "":

```
restClient.postToServer(myPath, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Retrofit rel.1.9 is prone by the issue (https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/854).

In the meantime, consider downgrading to rel.1.6 until current release will be fixed.
It is verified that rel.1.6 is free of this particular bug.

Answer (score 0):

just include in @Post Method

@Body String dummyValue , if body not required you must write this query and send "" to server

Answer (score 0):

downgrade OkHttp to version 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

`@Body String emptyBody` wasn't working for me as backend server I was working with, was returning `Bad request` and not accepting empty string as a body.

I've just sent empty JSON instead of empty String

`@POST("/some/url) 
Observable<Thing> doThing(@Body JsonElement empty);`

and then I just called my method like this:

`doThing(new JsonObject());`

Hope it will help if someone has similar problem.