# Failed to invoke public okhttp3.RequestBody() with no args

Tags: android, okhttp

1.This is the time I use retrofit mistakes

first step：

```
public interface RequestService {
    @POST ("home/indexThree")
    Call<RequestBody> getHomeinfo(@Body RequestBody info);
}
```

second step:

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
             .baseUrl(url)
             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
             .build();
    RequestService requestService = retrofit.create(RequestService.class);
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonObject.toString());
            Call<RequestBody> homeinfo = requestService.getHomeinfo(body);
    homeinfo.enqueue(new Callback<RequestBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RequestBody> call, Response<RequestBody> response) {
            System.out.println("response"+response.body().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RequestBody> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("onFailure"+t.getMessage().toString());
        }
    });
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. thx!

Comment: which mistake? Can you give logcat?

Comment: your question is very unclear but could be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358545/caused-by-retrofit-retrofiterror-method-post-must-have-a-request-body/30358749?noredirect=1#comment48809814_30358749

Comment: log：  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public okhttp3.RequestBody() with no args

Answer (score 1):

using `ResponseBody` instead of `requestbody`, resolved my case:

```
public interface RequestService {
@POST ("home/indexThree")
Call<ResponseBody> getHomeinfo(@Body RequestBody info);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Call<LoginModel>call=apiService.getForgotPassword(Utill.encodeString(json));call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginModel> call, 
        Response<LoginModel> response) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (response.body() != null) {
                LoginModel clientModel = response.body();
                if (clientModel.getResult().equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
                    Utill.showCenteredToast(LoginActivity.this, clientModel.getResult());

                    dialog.dismiss();
                } else {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Utill.showCenteredToast(LoginActivity.this, clientModel.getResult());
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem and I found the answer the question,I think you should write  `Call<ResponseBody>`

Answer (score -1):

use the correct Call model class of response from server  ,these error show because u use   Call.

Comment: use  call<Model>

Answer (score -1):

i met the probem yesterday,and finally sloved it.since retrofit is restful,the Call is not correct,it should be Call where the CallBackBean is the bean that return to you for your resquest.
see http://blog.csdn.net/u013795543/article/details/70948978 for details.

Comment: Your answer would be **greatly** improved if the relevant details were here. As it is, this *may* answer OP's question; but please show the updated code.